# New Image Replacement technique (Kellum/Zeldman) layout

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a new responsive site ... have a look at the homepage of > [www.living-heart.nl/txp](http://www.living-heart.nl/txp)

Everything is (almost) working according this IR technique > [www.zeldman.com](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/)

I've two questions:

1) I still can see a little bit of the H1 at the right (Firefox/Mac) ... you too? It can be hidden by giving H1 more text-indent ... 101% is enough. Is that OK to do?

2) If I disable images ... how can I get my text (H1) back?

Thanks for helping me.

```
/* New Image Replacement > http://wp.me/p4WtR-2xq */
hgroup {
    padding: 1em 0 0 0;
}
h1 {
    font-family: lavanderia_sturdysturdy, cursive;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 100%;
    background: url(../design/living-heart_logo-05.gif) no-repeat center 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 1.2em;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.8em;
    color: #6d8677;
    line-height: 1.2em; /* 120% van 16px */
    margin-bottom: 0;   
    font-family: 'IM Fell English', Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
}
```

Comment: What is new about this technique? I'm using it for years now…

Comment: It's a long time ago using IR so it's 'new' to me

Answer (score 1):

> 1) 101% is enough. Is that OK to do?

I always use a `text-indent: 110%;`; just to make sure it works (sometimes the text is visible on zooming into the page when having a value of `100%`)

> 2) If I disable images ... how can I get my text (H1) back?

There's no way to do so with this replacement technique.

You need, for example, the Shea image replacement method to do so. See the following linked WP article and search for "**Shea method**": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrner_Image_Replacement (this method requires an additional element inside the replaced one; could be possible to use pseudo elements here – I've never tried that)

Comment: Yes, that was my 'old' method ... but I'm working here with a .gif with a transparent background.

Comment: @redfox Then the possibilities to have the text displayed while images are not loaded are rare. You should check if this is really an important requirement to you/your client.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've used in the past - it's a bit simpler:

```
h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 span {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: -100%;
}
```

And the markup:

```
<h1>
  <span>
    My Title with lots of text so
    that if and when it wraps nothing 
    goes wrong, and I don't have to rely 
    on nowrap
  </span>
</h1>
```

This is because support for nowrap is not 100% reliable in certain agents. There is also benefit to having a secondary element to target as it means you have more control over what you do with the textual content.

You can obviously use positivte or negative margins. I prefer negative because in the unlikely event that `overflow:hidden` was to fail, shifting left is more likely to hide the text content, and it wont cause scroll bars to appear. As I said though it's down to personal preference.

#### Disabled images

Unfortunately can't help you with disabled/enabled images though, the only solution that I know of is the one already suggested by feeela - which obviously doesn't work for transparent images :/

Actually you do have one possibility, and that is to use multiple background images with the `Shea method`. So you basically repeat your page background and then layer your text image on top. However if you have a centered site, like you do, you'd have to make sure you can use `background-attachment: fixed` for it to work and align properly. Obviously though, this only works in browsers that support multiple background images... although you could add another element layer to fake this behaviour -- but then things start to get messy.

Answer (score 0):

There is an IR technique that does work with images disabled with no extra markup required:  http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-image-replacement-with-pseudo-elements/

```
.nir {
   height:100px; /* height of replacement image */
   width:400px; /* width of replacement image */
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.nir:before {
   content:url(image.gif);
   display:inline-block;
   font-size:0;
   line-height:0;
}
```

Older browsers don't understand `:before` or `content`, but at least they'll be able to see the text.